# FQL getting 0 counts for link_stat without access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm doing project for a customer. And we are using FQL link_stats to get the count to display on the website.

Recently it was working fine, and still working fine on our staging environment. However in the live site, we are getting zero counts.

This is a sample of the FQL.
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.channelnewsasia.com%2Fnews%2Fworld%2Fus-senators-reach-deal-on-gun-sale-backg%2F634558.html%22&callback=_ate.cbs.rcb_httpwwwchannelnewsasiacomnewsworldussenatorsreachdealongunsalebackg634558html0

And we notice that if we are to run the FQL in the FB debugger tool, with access token. We can get the correct results. But without access token it will get the same result as above.

I know that FB is changing this behavoir in july 2013 to make link_stat required access token. As mention in their roadmap. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/
However it is mention that this will only kick in after 10th July 2013 only.